# Derivation of rotational dynamics equation with moment of inertia changing

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I am trying to understand the equation:
$\vec M = I\dot {\vec\omega} + \vec \omega \times I\vec \omega  + \dot I\vec \omega  $

Source: https://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/customvariablemass6dofeulerangles.html

I can understand where the first two term in the RHS come from, but the last term $\dot I\vec \omega$ which account for change in moment of inertia, I can not understand. I know it is something related to Newton third law. I couldn't find on internet the derivation of this equation. Could anyone give me the link or help me understand this?

I thought it this way: similar to the translational equation which includes $V_{re}$ term, the rotational equation would be: $\vec M = I\dot {\vec\omega} + \vec \omega \times I\vec \omega  + \dot I\vec \omega_{re}  $. But this is not the same as the equation on the website: https://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/customvariablemass6dofeulerangles.html

Comment: I gave a detailed derivation of the Euler equation here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/575287/ - you might find it helpful!

Comment: @ArthurMorris I don't see the $\dot I$ term in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously, the angular momentum is $\vec{L}=I\vec{\omega}$, and the torque is

$$\vec{M}=\dfrac{d\vec{L}}{dt}$$

So you're just doing the derivative of a product.

Comment: I think you can not do the derivative. What you mean is analogous to the math: F = d(mV)/dt = (dm/dt)V + m(dV/dt). This is wrong I think.

Comment: Why can't you do a derivative, and why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: If we consider motion of a solid stone and a reference frame that is not fixed to the stone body, then I think you can do the derivative like normal. How about the case: a missile flying with constant mass of propellant expelled from missile? I think $\dot I$ due to mass being expelled from missile is not the same as $\dot I$ from solid stone case.

Comment: That's a different problem. $\dot{I}$ refers to a changing moment of inertia, which is usually due to an expansion or contraction (non rigid body). For your case of a missile, you should state that problem as a "reversed collision" of two rigid bodies

Comment: I understand that, so could the equation in the main question be applied to case of a missile? Which case can The Custom Variable Mass 6DOF in Simulink/MATLAB be used for?

Comment: I have seen this thread and he had same problem but I couldn't find anything satisfy me: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192855/rotational-dynamics-equation-for-a-variable-mass-system

Comment: I have added some infomation in the question, please help me. I thought the mass being expelled $\dot m$ has it own angular momentum then there might exist the term $\omega_{re}$ in the rotational equation.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand you. I don't know what you want from that website, I only see a bunch of variables and definitions. What's exactly your question?

Comment: I see, I will delete this question and post a new one. Thank you for your feedbacks.